# Why number of connected vertices of size $n$ on integer lattice of size $n$ grow exponentially?

Tags: combinatorics

Given an integer lattice of finite dimension $d$, we consider a hypercube of side length $n$. The total number of vertices on this cube is $n^d$. Count the number of subsets of vertices such that this subset is connected (each vertex in this subset has a neighbour in this subset also). Show that the number of such subsets grows exponentially with $n$.

Attempt: I thought of a recursive solution. Denote the number of such subsets with $n$ to be $S(n)$. Then $S(n+1)=S(n)+d\cdot n$ roughly since we may grow the subset by one bit by appending to it one neighbour of one of its elements (and there are $n$ elements currently). But this does not give exponential growth even after I remove the ordering $n!$.

Answer (score 1):

To show that there are at least $2^n$ such sets (if $n>1$ and $d>1$) is easy without explicitly counting them all: Just take sets consisting of one "column" together with an arbitrary subset of the $n$ hyperplanes perpendicular to the column.

Comment: Can you give an upper bound that is $O(\exp(n))$? This is the part I don't have.

Comment: @DanielLi The number of subsets is $\Theta(2^{n^d})$, not $O(\exp(n))$.